# Kohana ORM update column on save

Tags: php, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I'm fairly new to ORM, but what I am trying to do is insert a new comment in to the MySQL database and update users table.

So I have two tables, `users` and `comments`.

Now when i call `save()` method on comments object i would like to insert that comment in to `comments` table and also update user `written_comments` column in `users` table.

The part where I only need to insert comment is easy and I've already done it.

Problem comes with the update query where i need to update `users` table and set `written_comments + 1 where id = $userId`

I have found documentation about relations between objects, but i can't figure this out.

I am using Kohana 3.3 version.

My `comments` class right now is empty:

```
class Model_Comments extends ORM{

}
```

And I'm extending Auth user class

```
class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User  {

}
```

Any help at all would help a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want use only ORM, try write something like this after saving a comment

```
$user = ORM::factory('User', $userId);
if($user->loaded()){
   $user->set('written_comments', $user->written_comments + 1)->update();
}
```

There are no way to bind callback on ORM::save(). You can only check saving a comment into database with ORM::loaded() method.

Comment: After all day of struggling with this issue I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this. For example after saving user you can call `add` method which will call role object and then it will add user roles, please take a look at this: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#add
I came pretty close to what i want with this `add` method, but i can't fully understand the way relationships work.

Comment: add method create many-to-many relations in DB between 2 tables. For example `$user->add('roles', 1);` create record in `roles_users` table. If you create correct relation many-to-one between Model_Comments  and Model_Users you can write `$comment->user->set('written_comments', $comment->user->written_comments + 1)->update();`. But as for me, in this case relations is not necessary